# variable is not a CFStringRef

Tags: iphone, cfstring

I have this:

```
partenaire_lat = 48.8160525; 
partenaire_lng = 2.3257800;
```

And obtain a NSString like this:

```
NSString *endPoint =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", partenaire_lat, partenaire_lng];
```

and after using this NSString in some context I get this stupid error:

```
Variable is not a CFString.
```

But if I create the NSString like this:

`endPoint = @"48.8160525,2.3257800"` it then works perfect!

For this error `Variable is not a CFString` I tried the following:

```
NSString *endPoint1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", partenaire_lat, partenaire_lng];
CFStringRef endPoint =(CFStringRef)endPoint1;
```

and tried to use `endPoint` but not working neither this way.Anyone any miraculous idea?Thx

```
EDIT:partenaire_lat and partenaire_lng are both NSString!!
```

Comment: What context are you using endPoint in?

Comment: What hypercrypt said. You haven't actually shown the line that is causing the error.

Comment: There's nothing stupid about the error - it is telling you *exactly* what is wrong.

Comment: @Abizern you woke up and thought you should give me an -1?

Comment: The best bet is to believe the error message, the trick is to understand the programming error that caused the message.

Comment: @george - what makes you think it was me? Also what do you mean by "woke up?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
partenaire_lat = 48.8160525; 
partenaire_lng = 2.3257800;
```

You keep saying that the two variables are `NSString`s but you aren't assigning `NSString`s to them. You need to assign `NSString` objects to `NSString` variables - they aren't created for you automatically.

So the answers which are telling you to use formatted strings are correct. You really should be doing it like this:

```
partenaire_lat = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 48.8160525] retain]; 
partenaire_lng = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 2.3257800] retain];
```

Answer (score 2):

You code has several potential problems:

1. %@ format specifier expects object parameter, while it looks like you pass plain float (I may be wrong here as there's not enough context to be sure). Change format to %f to fix your problem if that's really the case:

   ```
   NSString *endPoint1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", partenaire_lat, partenaire_lng];
   ```
2. Your endPoint1 string is **autoreleased** and may become invalid outside of current scope if you don't retain it. So if you try to use your variable in another method you probably should retain it.

Comment: %@ is the specifier for object, not NSString (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

what are lat and lng? i'm assuming float or double..so you should use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", lat, lng];` (or however you want the floats to be formatted)

Comment: then it is as vladimir pointed out in his edit..it is getting autoreleased somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do

```
NSString *latStr=[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:partenaire_lat] stringValue];
NSString *lngStr=[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:partenaire_lng] stringValue];
```

and do whatever you want to do with these two string :)

Comment: I think it's overkill to turn a `float` into an `NSNumber` just to turn it into an `NSString` when you can do it directly.